# Only compare values of matching keys in two dictionaries in python

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

What is the most pythonic way of simply comparing:

```
dict1 = {'Class1': 10, 'Class2': 18, 'Class3': 5}
dict2 = {'Class1': 10, 'Class2': 18, 'Class4': 11}

for key in dict1:
    for key2 in dict2:
        if key == key2:
            self.assertEqual(dict1[key], dict2[key2])
```

I feel like my solution of doing a nested for loop to compare all of dict2 keys to each key in dict1 is inefficient. The goal is to only compare the value for the keys that both dict1 and dict2 have.

Comment: **You're not telling us what the output you want is.** Do we only compare for equality, i.e. your result is one giant boolean ("all equal"), or a dict of booleans? or a dict of numerical differences? or what?

Comment: What is your solution ? which you think is inefficient.

Comment: Sorry about that, I added an example for more clarity

Comment: @JackLiaiea Please don't add answers inside your question. If you have a seperate answer simply post it as another answer (or better [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) or upvote the answers)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on @Mitch's answer you can compare them inside `all`:

```
dict1 = {'Class1': 10, 'Class2': 18, 'Class3': 5}
dict2 = {'Class1': 10, 'Class2': 18, 'Class4': 11}
all(dict1[k] == dict2[k] for k in dict1.keys() & dict2.keys())
```

or in your case:

```
self.assertTrue(all(dict1[k] == dict2[k] for k in dict1.keys() & dict2.keys()))
```

Comment: Yeah I wasn't sure what OP actually wanted to _do_ before the edit, but this is good!

Answer (score 3):

You can get the key intersection on which to iterate and compare with

```
dict1.keys() & dict2.keys()
```

For instance,

```
>>> {k: (dict1[k], dict2[k]) for k in dict1.keys() & dict2.keys()}
{'Class1': (10, 10), 'Class2': (18, 18)}

# or 

>>> for k in dict1.keys() & dict2.keys():
        print(dict1[k], dict2[k])

18 18
10 10
```